# Cordova FileTransfer.download success callback method never fires

Tags: javascript, angularjs, file, cordova, file-transfer

I am using angularjs, org.apache.cordova.file 1.3.3 "File" org.apache.cordova.file-transfer 0.5.0 "File Transfer", VS2013 on a windows 8.1 machine and I am using a loop to download a bunch of images.

I set up break points at the beginning of the download method and in each of the callbacks. Then I step through and see that sometimes it goes to the error callback and sometimes it doesn't go to any callback, this makes me think that it is successful but it never gets to the successful callback.

```
     downloadFile: function () {

        var downloadDefer = $q.defer();

        var fileTransfer = new FileTransfer();

        var url = "https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png";
        var uri = encodeURI(url);

        var filePath = encodeURI(window._CORDOVA_FS_ROOT + fileName);

        fileTransfer.download(
            uri,
            filePath,
            function (file) {
                console.log(file);
                downloadDefer.resolve(file);
            },
            function (error) {
                console.log(error);
                downloadDefer.reject(error);
            },
            true
        );

        return downloadDefer.promise;

    }
```